# How to sort json files and compare?

Tags: json, testing, jackson, compare, testng

I have two json files which are similar but in different order. So the tests are failing while comparing. Can anyone suggest how to sort the json files before comparing them.

I have two json files which are similar but in different order. So the tests are failing while comparing. Can anyone suggest how to sort the json files before comparing them.
Thanks in advance.

JSON-1

```
    {
"RowHeaders":[
     [
            {
                "DimensionName": "Account",
                "Label": "1013ETL",
                "MemberId": "1203"
            },
            {
                "DimensionName": "Measures",
                "Label": "MTD",
                "MemberId": "MTD"
            },
            {
                "DimensionName": "Reporting",
                "Label": "Consolidated (CC)",
                "MemberId": "14"
            }
        ],
        
      [
            {
                "DimensionName": "Account",
                "Label": "2010ETL - A/P - Trade",
                "MemberId": "1210"
            },
            {
                "DimensionName": "Measures",
                "Label": "YTD",
                "MemberId": "YTD"
            },
            {
                "DimensionName": "Reporting",
                "Label": "Consolidated (CC)",
                "MemberId": "14"
            }
        ],

       [
            {
                "DimensionName": "Account",
                "Label": "3030ETL - Retained Earnings - Beginning of Year",
                "MemberId": "1221"
            },
            {
                "DimensionName": "Measures",
                "Label": "YTD",
                "MemberId": "YTD"
            },
            {
                "DimensionName": "Reporting",
                "Label": "Consolidated (CC)",
                "MemberId": "14"
            }
        ]
     ],
    "Status":"Success",
     "StatusMessage":""
    }
```

JSON-2

```
{
"RowHeaders":[
       [
            {
                "DimensionName": "Account",
                "Label": "1013ETL",
                "MemberId": "1203"
            },
            {
                "DimensionName": "Measures",
                "Label": "MTD",
                "MemberId": "MTD"
            },
            {
                "DimensionName": "Reporting",
                "Label": "Consolidated (CC)",
                "MemberId": "14"
            }
        ],
        
        [
            {
                "DimensionName": "Account",
                "Label": "3030ETL - Retained Earnings - Beginning of Year",
                "MemberId": "1221"
            },
            {
                "DimensionName": "Measures",
                "Label": "YTD",
                "MemberId": "YTD"
            },
            {
                "DimensionName": "Reporting",
                "Label": "Consolidated (CC)",
                "MemberId": "14"
            }
        ],
        
        [
            {
                "DimensionName": "Account",
                "Label": "2010ETL - A/P - Trade",
                "MemberId": "1210"
            },
            {
                "DimensionName": "Measures",
                "Label": "YTD",
                "MemberId": "YTD"
            },
            {
                "DimensionName": "Reporting",
                "Label": "Consolidated (CC)",
                "MemberId": "14"
            }
        ]
     ],
"Status":"Success",
 "StatusMessage":""
}
```

Comment: parse the json to an object and use comparator?

Comment: if you do not want to compare the values use JSON Schema to check for schema validation for both